# can't get updated redux state from axios response interceptor

Tags: redux, axios, redux-toolkit

I'm using axios interceptors to handle csrf-token stuff, my interceptors codes are like below:

```js
axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
  function (config) {
    const {
      user:{ csrfToken } //csrfToken is a string includes 10 csrf-tokens concatenated by comma, like this: 'token,token,token,token,...'
    } = store.getState();
    if (csrfToken) {
      const [first] = csrfToken.split(',');
      config.headers['x-csrf-token'] = first; //get the first token and put it on the request header
      store.dispatch(shiftCsrfToken(config.url)); //concatenate the rest tokens with comma and put it on redux state
    }
    return config
  }
)
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    const responseToken = response.headers['x-csrf-token'].split(','); //backend sent back csrf-token
    const {
      user: { csrfToken },
    } = store.getState();
    if(csrfToken) {
      store.dispatch(pushCsrfToken(response.headers['x-csrf-token']));//if there is csrfToken on redux store, put the new token on the end of csrfToken
    } else {
      store.dispatch(setCsrfToken(response.headers['x-csrf-token'])); //if there is no csrfToken, replace redux state with the new token
    }
  }
)
```

the problem is when I was calling a certain api, the csrfToken I got in the response interceptor from redux store is not updated (the first token of the csrfToken should have been removed, but not), resulting in the consumed token was put on redux state again, and it would be used in next api call.
I'm pretty sure the shiftCsrfToken method works, because the other api call works great, but the problem only occurs when a certain api get called.
quiet annonyed about this problem, hope there is someone could solve this.

Hope I can get the updated redux state in response interceptor function.

Comment: Why do you keep the token in redux at all? Isn't it only required by this one axios instance?